# Getting 0 (zero) from properly defined PHP object property

Tags: php, object, properties, dump, zero

I have a PHP object stored in var `$category` which has the following properties (dumped with `print_r()`):

```
jstandCategory Object
(
    [category_id] => 1
    [category_image] => 
    [category_parent_id] => 0
    [category_publish] => 1
    [category_ordertype] => 1
    [category_template] => default
    [category_ordering] => 1
    [category_add_date] => 2013-03-18 22:10:45
    [cars_page] => 6
    [cars_row] => 1
    [name_en-GB] => Used Cars
    [alias_en-GB] => used-cars
    [short_description_en-GB] => 
    [description_en-GB] => <table>... some html code ...</table>
)
```

However, when i try to dump `name_en-GB` property using `print_r($category->name_en-GB);` i get `0`. What am i doing wrong? Properties above `name_en-GB` are dumped just fine.

Answer (score 4):

PHP understands it as `$category->name_en` - `GB` (math operation), a `NULL - NULL` situation, which is 0.

Better don't use hypens in property names. Use underscore or camelCase if you prefer.

Comment: Great! If the problem is solved you can accept an answer. Welcome to stackoverflow btw :)

Answer (score 2):

```
- is an operator don't use it in variable names
```

Answer (score 2):

You're using a property name with an invalid character, you'd need to wrap the name in curly braces to have it be recognised

```
print_r($category->{'name_en-GB'});
```

It would be better if you changed the naming strategy though